# How to associate DeploymentPipeline to an Application in deployit-manifest.xml

Tags: xl-deploy

When importing a dar in XLDeploy server for an application the first time, I would like to have the application associated to a DeploymentPipeline already defined in XLDeploy.
How can do that?
Is it possible to add deploymentPackageProperty in maven configuration to have a property in deployit-manifest.xml doing that at dar import?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. One way to do this is by invoking the [CLI](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/concept/getting-started-with-the-xl-deploy-cli.html) first to create the application and setting that property specifically.